# Answer Without Qualification

Tags: support, asking-questions

I've read the FAQs on both sites and I'm still not sure where to ask this, so I'll start here.  The amount of information regarding both sites is overwhelming for sure.

Anyway, I'd like to ask a question on Stack Exchange, but the requirements are that I first need to "answer" a question that is deemed acceptable to the powers that be.  What if I'm not qualified to answer some of the questions?  Any help or direction is appreciated.

---

So I tried resubmitting my question and because I used the tag "asp", I got an error saying I needed 1500 reputation points. I removed the tag and was able to post the question. Note that I'm coding in ASP so I thought it would be relevant to include that tag.

Comment: You...should be able to ask a question without issue, unless you've hit a rate limit or question ban.

Comment: _"but the requirements are that I first need to "answer" a question that is deemed acceptable to the powers that be."_ Where did you get that from? Can you cite the FAQ in your question and disclose the site where that's written please?

Comment: "I've read the FAQs on both sites" - there are more than 100 sites on the network, could you be a tad more specific?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to answer a question before being able to ask one. On some sites you don't even need to register. Posting questions requires [1 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) which you get by default.

You ran into an error because you tried to create a new tag, which requires [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). You should always favor existing tags instead, e.g. [[asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)]. This wasn't immediately clear from your initial question here, so please be specific at all times (exact error messages and/or screenshots are always helpful).

On (most) child meta sites, e.g. [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), you do need [5 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) to post a question but you need that to post an answer as well. (Actually, you can ask a question with 1 reputation but only if it's *about* one of your main site questions.) This site, Meta Stack Exchange, is another exception in that here you don't need (more than 1) reputation to participate, you just need an account.

Comment: So I tried resubmitting my question and because I used the tag "asp", I got an error saying I needed 1500 reputation points.  I removed the tag and was able to post the question.  Note that I'm coding in ASP so I thought it would be relevant to include that tag.

Comment: I think it's the same error message you initially got. Please add those details to this question so we can remove the 'on hold' status.